Do I need to add firebase-crashlytics-gradle?
Following this docs, looks like we no need to use firebase-crashlytics-gradle any more?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android
Do I need to add as below?
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'


Yes, you need to add the firebase-crashlytics-gradle plugin to the project, if you need to add firebase crashlytics in your project then compulsory to add this in your project level build.gradle or build.gradle.ktx
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "3.0.2" apply false

